# How to solve Ajax post type Cross-Origin Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, azure, cross-domain

I'm using Ajax post type to get a token from Azure , But I get Cross-Origin error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

Ajax example:

```
 $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: success
});
```

How to override this problem ? Is there is an option for Ajax to add? Is there is an alternative way using Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: Check what CORS is. The server-side must authorize your domain to make requests.

Comment: You need to ask your server development team (or the person who is handling Azure) to enable CORS for you. For more information you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services

Comment: If you are using google Chrome, you can enable the CORS with a plugin and test your request.